# Why search by channel return no_videos_140.png inside media$thumbnail tag?

Tags: youtube-api

Direct access channel info by userid, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/Lm-kPkFGRaV0t55q7-VwgQ?alt=json&safeSearch=strict&restriction=MY , i can get http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/silhouette250-vflEqxKg9.png from media$thumbnail tag
[image]

However, Search by channel API query, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?alt=json&q=ghghghgh&start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2&safeSearch=strict&restriction=MY, i get http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/no_videos_140.png from media$thumbnail tag
[image]

Visit https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ghghghgh&filters=channel&lclk=channel with web browser, i can see http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/silhouette250-vflEqxKg9.png
[image]

My question is, how do i get http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/silhouette250-vflEqxKg9.png using search by channel API(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?alt=json&q=), instead of http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/no_videos_140.png?

**Update: i wonder only if the user have yt$googlePlusUserId, then it would no problem, example is user http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCBJ7AiDylXmwgUlSQFM2luw?alt=json&safeSearch=strict&restriction=MY&prettyprint=True&fields=yt:googlePlusUserId**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using v3 of the YouTube Data API.  If you make the following call to the Search resource, it will return three different thumbnails to choose from.  If the channel hasn't uploaded a thumbnail, it will be the same image as the silhouette you referenced, but with a unique url for the channel.  The advantage of using this url as your img source is that if the channel decides to upload a thumbnail, you won't have to change your image reflect that change.

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=ghghghgh&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=ghghghgh&type=channel&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"O7gZuruiUnq-GRpzm3HckV3Vx7o/PaWiOpjYBhvp7UVKUk3QeiagLtw\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 33,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCLm-kPkFGRaV0t55q7-VwgQ"
   },
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"O7gZuruiUnq-GRpzm3HckV3Vx7o/x_NADGr-4b04fqoDn_uRBGj99eQ\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-03-13T04:10:45.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCLm-kPkFGRaV0t55q7-VwgQ",
    "title": "barrett90",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "http://i.ytimg.com/i/Lm-kPkFGRaV0t55q7-VwgQ/1.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "http://i.ytimg.com/i/Lm-kPkFGRaV0t55q7-VwgQ/mq1.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "http://i.ytimg.com/i/Lm-kPkFGRaV0t55q7-VwgQ/hq1.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

You can get an API Key here:
https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: Thanks for response, however i need to maintain my current code which using version 2 within short-term.